# How do I use the OwnerID of the record to get related fields from the the user in a class?

Tags: apex, class, owner

This is what the current class looks like but I wish to do the same now with the OwnerID instead of User.

```
public with sharing class BranchService {
    
    public static Id getUsersBranchInfo(Id userId) {
        User relatedUser = [
            SELECT Branch_Number__c, Branch_Region__c, Branch_State__c
            FROM User
            WHERE Id =: userId
        ];

        if(relatedUser.Branch_Number__c == null || relatedUser.Branch_Region__c == null || relatedUser.Branch_State__c == null)
            return null;

        List<Branch__c> relatedBranch = [
            SELECT Id
            FROM Branch__c
            WHERE Branch_Number__c =: relatedUser.Branch_Number__c
                AND Market__r.Region__c =: relatedUser.Branch_Region__c
                AND Market__r.State__c =: relatedUser.Branch_State__c
        ];

        return relatedBranch.IsEmpty() ? null : relatedBranch[0].Id;
    }

    public static void setBranchesForCase(List<Case> caseList) {
        Id branchId = getUsersBranchInfo(UserInfo.getUserId());
        for(Case currentCase : caseList) {
            if(currentCase.Branch__c == null) 
            currentCase.Branch__c = branchId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to change getUsersBranchInfo to return a Map<Id, Id> and allow it to accept an set of user IDs. So try something like:

```
public with sharing class BranchService {
    
    public static Map<Id, Id> getUsersBranchInfo(Set<Id> userIds) {
        // Load all the users required, including their IDs for later use
        User relatedUsers = [
            SELECT Id, Branch_Number__c, Branch_Region__c, Branch_State__c
            FROM User
            WHERE Id IN :userIds
        ];

        // I don't know what types these fields are
        Set<???> numbers = new Set<???>();
        Set<???> regions = new Set<???>();
        Set<???> states = new Set<???>();

        // Build sets for the numbers, regions and states for branches we need
        for (User relatedUser : relatedUsers) {
            if (relatedUser.Branch_Number__c != null) {
                numbers.add(relatedUser.Branch_Number__c);
            }

            if (relatedUser.Branch_Region__c != null) {
                regions.add(relatedUser.Branch_Region__c);
            }

            if (relatedUser.Branch_State__c != null) {
                states.add(relatedUser.Branch_State__c);
            }
        }

        // If any one set is empty give up
        if (branches.isEmpty() || regions.isEmpty() || states.isEmpty()) {
            return new Map<Id, Id>();
        }

        // Load all branches that look like the map to users (this probably loads
        // more than need, but at least loads all that is needed)
        List<Branch__c> relatedBranches = [
            SELECT Id,
                   Branch_Number__c,
                   Market__r.Region__c,
                   Market__r.State__c
            FROM Branch__c
            WHERE Branch_Number__c IN :numbers
                AND Market__r.Region__c IN :regions
                AND Market__r.State__c IN :states
        ];

        // Now we want to set up easy look-up of branches based on their number, region
        // and state. I have assumed that you never have more than one branch with a
        // given combination of these three values
        Map<Object[], Branch__c> branchesByKey = new Map<Object[], Branch__c>();

        for (Branch__c branch : relatedBranches) {
            branchesByKey.put(new Object[] { Branch_Number__c,
                   Market__r.Region__c,
                   Market__r.State__c }, branch);
        }

        // Finally we can build the map of user ID to branch ID
        Map<Id, Id> branchIdByUserId = new Map<Id, Id>();

        for (User user : relatedUsers) {
            branchIdByUserId.put(user.Id, branchesByKey.get(new Object[] {
                user.Branch_Number__c, user.Branch_Region__c, user.Branch_State__c }));
        }

        return branchIdByUserId;
    }

    // If currentUser is true use the current user's detail, otherwise use the case
    // owners
    public static void setBranchesForCase(List<Case> caseList, Boolean currentUser) {
        Map<Id, Id> branchIdByUserId;

        if (currentUser) {
            branchIdByUserId = getUserBranches(new Set<Id> { UserInfo.getUserId() });
        } else {
            Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();

            for (Case case : caseList) {
                ownerIds.add(case.OwnerId);
            }

            branchIdByUserId = getUserBranches(ownerIds);
        }

        for (Case currentCase : caseList) {
            if (currentCase.Branch__c == null) {
                if (currentUser) {
                    currentCase.Branch__c = branchIdByUserId.get(UserInfo.getUserId());
                } else {
                    currentCase.Branch__c = branchIdByUserId.get(currentCase.OwnerId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This retains the ability to set by current user's ID or via the case owner IDs. You'll see there are various hoops to jump to get the right details into the branch IDs by user ID map.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I wanted to replace using the user complete and just use Owner?

Comment: Then just take out the "currentUser" handling. There's only two usages of this new parameter. Only keep the "else" logic parts in both cases.